# Как сделать точки в пагинации React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Логику сделал, все работает. Но точки не работают. Нужно показывать точки перед последней страницей. И показывать номер последней страницы. А первые номера по мере переключения сдвигать. То есть вначале должно быть 10 номеров, потом ... и последняя страница

[image: Вот что получилось на данном этапе]

Компонент Pagination.
totalPages - Number

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './Pagination.scss'

export default function Pagination({ totalPages, onPageChange }) {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([])
  const [selectedPage, setSelectedPage] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    getNumbersPages(totalPages)
  }, [totalPages])

  const getNumbersPages = totalPages => {
    let pagesNumber = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
      pagesNumber.push(i + 1);
    }
    setPages(pagesNumber)
  };

  const handlePageChangeLeft = (e) => {
    onPageChange(e)
    if (selectedPage <= 1) {
      return
    } else {
      setSelectedPage(selectedPage - 1)
    }
  }

  const handlePageChangeRight = (e) => {
    onPageChange(e)
    if (selectedPage >= pages.length) {
      return
    } else {
      setSelectedPage(selectedPage + 1)
    }
  }

  const handlePageChange = (e, page) => {
    onPageChange(e)
    setSelectedPage(Number(page))
  }

  return (
    <div className='pagination'>
      <button className="pagination__btn pagination__btn--left" data-page={selectedPage} onClick={(e) => handlePageChangeLeft(e)}>{selectedPage === 1 ? selectedPage : selectedPage - 1}</button>
      <div className="pagination__numbers">
        {pages.map((page, i) => (
          <div>
            { /// вот здесь не могу додуматся алгоритм
              i < selectedPage+11 &&
              <div key={page} data-page={selectedPage} className={selectedPage === page ? 'pagination__page pagination__page--active' : 'pagination__page'} onClick={(e) => handlePageChange(e, page)}>
                {page === selectedPage+10 ? '...' : page}
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button className="pagination__btn pagination__btn--right" data-page={selectedPage} onClick={(e) => handlePageChangeRight(e)}>{selectedPage === totalPages ? selectedPage : selectedPage + 1}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Мой баг
[image: Результат]